# New unallocated space goes back to the partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to free some space after an Ext4 partition. Gparted first resizes the partition and shows unallocated space after the partition but after few seconds,the newly unallocated space goes back to the partition, as if nothing has happened at all! A new alert icon is shown on partition list and if I check the partition, gparted grows the partition size to the original value.

[image: Image of the gparted after partitioning]

Comment: `/dev/sdb` is not a partition but the whole disk, thus it's not resizable. You don't free space after an ext4 partition, there is no partition. Best to see output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` to see if your filesystem spans over the whole disk or need to be resized.